# Why inheritance need to be "subclass" NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass, nsobject

Why inheritance must start with a NSObject and then use inheritance in another class?

Wonder why I have a subclass "FatherClass" from UIViewController.
So I want to create a inheritance FatherClass (ChildClass: FatherClass).

I can not do this, I get an error log.
All examples I searched here and Google begin with NSObject as a father.

So my question has to be so? Or am I wrong somewhere.

Here is the error log

```
#0  0x33d6c6f8 in CFStringGetCharacters ()
CoreFoundation`CFStringGetCharacters:
0x33d6c6f8:  push.w {r8, r10}
```

Thanks

**EDIT HERE with the code**

FatherClass.h

```
@class ChildClass;
@interface FatherClass : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation>
{
     //Some variables
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChildClass   *sidebar_table_controller;

-(void) show_modal: (id) sender; // Thats the Method i want to call
@end
```

FatherClass.m

```
#import "FatherClass.h"
#import "ChildClass.h"
@interface FatherClass ()

@end

@implementation FatherClass

@synthesize sidebar_table_controller;

// All inits here... DidiLoad, DidUnload, etc..

-(void) show_modal: (id) sender // Thats the Method!!!
{

      // All initiate ChildClass an then.. present modal

      [self presentModalViewController:self.sidebar_table_controller animated:YES];

      NSLog(@"Clicked ?...%@", sender);
}
@end
```

Now the Child

ChildClass.h

```
@interface ChildClass : FatherClass <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end
```

ChildClass.m

```
#import "ChildClass.h"

@interface ChildClass ()

@end

@implementation ChildClass
 // All inits here... DidiLoad, DidUnload, etc..

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Here i want to call Father Method
     [FatherClass show_modal:indexPath];
}

@end
```

When i change ChildClass : UIViewController to ChildClass : FatherClass my app crash.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with inheriting from UIViewController. Show your code for how you're creating "FatherClass" and "ChildClass". Do you get any errors or warnings from the compiler when creating those classes?

Comment: The strange thing is that this is the only error when using BreakPoint and without BreakPoint.
But I'll edit my question and enter the code to you see.

Comment: If there are no compiler errors or warnings associated with the code you're using to create your subclasses of UIViewController, then a stack backtrace may be necessary. One single x86 instruction inside CFStringGetCharacters() really isn't enough context to give any idea what's going on.

Comment: The code was edited, please see if it better now, thanks

Comment: It looks like show_modal is an instance method, but you are trying to call a class method of FatherClass.

Answer (score 1):

You can create every type of object : object with a NSObject father or a new object without any father.
So the question is: why to use NSObject as a father? Because it implement every method you need to create a robust class, like init, dealloc and much more.

So you can create your own hierarchy, but you have to reinvent the wheel rewriting every single method to manage an object.

Comment: I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I just want to run a method that the father has and the only method that needs to run his father, not son. But the child must call and follow the father. It became more clear? or was it harder?

Comment: Ok, I understood. You want something like trojanfoe answer, but if you have already implemeneted that as you write, I think that isn't related with your problem.
Can you post some code to see how you implement the classes?

Comment: Ok, thanks. The first error I see is this one: [FatherClass show_modal:indexPath];
the method "show_modal" isn't a class method but an instance method, so if you want to call it you have to do one of this:
- Create a new FatherClass object and then call it
- Extend Child from father and use [self show_modal:indexPath];

Can you try? Let me now!

Comment: you mean this: fatherclass *ThaFather = [[fatherclass alloc] init];
And then [ThaFather show_modal:indexPath]; ? Thats it ? I Already do that, i forgot to put on the code i edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call parent class properties and function with Self. So you code goes as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Here i want to call Father Method
     [Self show_modal:indexPath]; }
```

And You have never assigned property before presenting

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChildClass   *sidebar_table_controller;
```

So assing the property and call the function as above.